# Android Studio cannot be opened

Tags: android

```
Last login: Sat Dec  2 21:43:23 on ttys000
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ; exit;                 
mac@Lovelldebijibendiannao ~ % /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ; exit;
2023-12-02 22:11:50.970 studio[41359:1877265] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2023-12-02 22:11:50.972 studio[41359:1877269] Current Directory: /Users/mac
2023-12-02 22:11:50.972 studio[41359:1877269] parseVMOptions: STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS = /Users/mac/Documents/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/studio.vmoptions
2023-12-02 22:11:50.974 studio[41359:1877269] parseVMOptions: platform=-1 user=-1 file=(null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow should only be instantiated on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018228a800 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181d81eb4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001822afb4c _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001859ff538 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 188
    4   AppKit                              0x0000000185b58aac -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 48
    5   AppKit                              0x00000001859ff470 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 48
    6   AppKit                              0x0000000185b58a60 -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 48
    7   AppKit                              0x00000001859fe1f0 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 216
    8   AppKit                              0x00000001859d1434 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 212
    9   AppKit                              0x00000001859d0e00 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 252
    10  AppKit                              0x00000001859c69e0 loadNib + 340
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001859c6010 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 560
    12  AppKit                              0x00000001859c5d14 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 180
    13  AppKit                              0x0000000185c90658 -[NSAlert init] + 92
    14  studio                              0x0000000100b3d288 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 1144
    15  studio                              0x0000000100b3d890 -[Launcher launch] + 312
    16  Foundation                          0x0000000183315ff4 __NSThread__start__ + 716
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182139034 _pthread_start + 136
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182133e3c thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[进程已完成]
```

After forcibly closing the Gradle software when I downloaded the android studio version 2022.3.1.21 on my mac computer, I could not open the software later, nor could I open it after deleting the software again